# How to override a struct in a derived FB

Tags: oop, codesys

I'm stuck while designing a basic FB for our machine using OOP principles.

A machine uses different modules like this:

```
module1 : BaseModuleFB;
module2 : BaseModuleFB;
```

A module (some part of the machine) needs data to function (like positions, delays, etc.) This data will be stored in a recipe so grouping the data in a struct makes sence.

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK BaseModuleFB
VAR
     Data : BaseModuleDataStruct;
END_VAR
```

Now I have a different machine with some extra requirement. And also some extra data is needed. So I extend the module:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK ModuleWithExtraFunctionFB EXTENDS BaseModuleFB
VAR
     Data : ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct;
END_VAR
```

The code above will not compile because the variable Data is already in use in the base class.

The Data structs look like this by the way:

```
TYPE BaseModuleDataStruct:
STRUCT
    position1:INT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

TYPE ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct EXTENDS BaseModuleDataStruct:
STRUCT
    position2:INT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

Another option I thought of was creating a property called `Data`.
This property can be overritten by the derived class.

But this approach also failed because you cannot change the type of the overridden property.

Maybe someone has some nice ideas about this?
Thanks.

Comment: I deal with this all the time, and as much as I would like a satisfying solution and am interested in answers, I need to as : why not call your additional structure instance "ExtraData", have it NOT inherit your first structure, and just deal with two structures containing entirely separate variables in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just move the contents of the struct into the function block:

```pascal
FUNCTION_BLOCK BaseModuleFB
VAR
    // instead of "Data : BaseModuleDataStruct;"
    position1: INT;
END_VAR

FUNCTION_BLOCK ModuleWithExtraFunctionFB EXTENDS BaseModuleFB
VAR
    // instead of "Data : ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct;"
    position2: INT;
    // you can access both "position1" and position2" here
END_VAR
```

If you need to have the data in structures, the simplest way would be to just use several structures (as pointed by [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657716/how-to-override-a-struct-in-a-derived-fb#comment128343689_72657716)):

```pascal
FUNCTION_BLOCK BaseModuleFB
VAR
    Data : BaseModuleDataStruct;
END_VAR

FUNCTION_BLOCK ModuleWithExtraFunctionFB EXTENDS BaseModuleFB
VAR
    // Data is already available here.
    Data2 : ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct;
END_VAR
```

---

If you absolutely must access a single structure inside your function block, there is no simple way to do it in a completely enclosed way, however, you could pass the responsibility of defining the struct to the user of the function block and inject it either by using interfaces or pointers:

**1. For interfaces, we will use the [__QUERYINTERFACE](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_operator_queryinterface/) operator.**

```pascal
// An interface with a Method/Property that gives the Data structure
// It needs to extend "__System.IQueryInterface" for us to be bale to use the "__QUERYINTERFACE" operator on it later
INTERFACE IDataProvider EXTENDS __System.IQueryInterface
METHOD GetModuleAData : BaseModuleDataStruct

// An interface extension that adds a Method/Property that gives the extended Data structure
INTERFACE IDataProviderB EXTENDS IDataProvider
METHOD GetModuleBData : ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct

FUNCTION_BLOCK BaseModuleFB
VAR
    _dataProvider: IDataProvider;
END_VAR
METHOD FB_Init: BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains: BOOL; // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    bInCopyCode: BOOL;  // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    dataProvider: IDataProvider;
END_VAR
// Inside the FB_Init method: "THIS^._dataProvider := dataProvider;"


FUNCTION_BLOCK ModuleWithExtraFunctionFB EXTENDS BaseModuleFB
VAR
    _dataProviderB: IDataProviderB;
END_VAR
METHOD FB_Init: BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains: BOOL; // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    bInCopyCode: BOOL;  // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    dataProvider: IDataProvider;
    // We will use the __QUERYINTERFACE operator to "cast" IDataProvider to IDataProviderB
END_VAR
VAR
    success: BOOL;
END_VAR
// Inside the FB_Init method:
// success := __QUERYINTERFACE(_dataProvider, _dataProviderB);
```

Then in the base methods you should be able to use `_dataProvider.GetModuleAData` and in the extended methods `_dataProviderB.GetModuleBData`.

---

**2. For raw pointers, we can just pass them:**

```pascal
FUNCTION_BLOCK BaseModuleFB
VAR
    pdata: POINTER TO BaseModuleDataStruct;
END_VAR
METHOD SetData: BOOL
VAR_IN_OUT
    data: BaseModuleDataStruct;
END_VAR
// Inside the SetDatamethod: "THIS^.pdata:= ADR(data);"


FUNCTION_BLOCK ModuleWithExtraFunctionFB EXTENDS BaseModuleFB
VAR
    pdata2: POINTER TO ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct;
END_VAR
METHOD SetData: BOOL
VAR_IN_OUT
    data: BaseModuleDataStruct;
END_VAR
// Inside the SetDatamethod: "THIS^.pdata:= ADR(data);"
//                           "THIS^.pdata2:= ADR(data);"
// We are assuming that the user passed data of type "ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct" here!!!
// Care needs to be taken here, otherwise we may get access violations!
```

In your Program on the first run call the `SetData` methods for both Function Blocks. Make sure you are passing the correct data struct to avoid any access violations!

Then in the base methods you should be able to use `pdata^.position1` and in the extended methods `pdata2^position2`.

---

**3. We could also combine the two for direct access to the structure while retaining the type safety of interfaces:**

```pascal
INTERFACE IDataProvider EXTENDS __System.IQueryInterface
METHOD GetDataAPtr : POINTER TO BaseModuleDataStruct

INTERFACE IDataProviderB EXTENDS IDataProvider
METHOD GetDataBPtr : POINTER TO ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct

FUNCTION_BLOCK BaseModuleFB
VAR
    pdata: POINTER TO BaseModuleDataStruct;
END_VAR
METHOD FB_Init: BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains: BOOL; // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    bInCopyCode: BOOL;  // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    dataProvider: IDataProvider;
END_VAR
// Inside the FB_Init method: "THIS^.pdata:= dataProvider.GetDataAPtr();"


FUNCTION_BLOCK ModuleWithExtraFunctionFB EXTENDS BaseModuleFB
VAR
    pdata2: POINTER TO ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct;
END_VAR
METHOD FB_Init: BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains: BOOL; // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    bInCopyCode: BOOL;  // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    dataProvider: IDataProvider;
END_VAR
VAR
    success: BOOL;
    _dataProviderB: IDataProviderB;
END_VAR
// Inside the FB_Init method:
// success := __QUERYINTERFACE(_dataProvider, _dataProviderB);
// IF (success) THEN
//     THIS^.pdata2 := _dataProviderB.GetDataBPtr();
// END_IF
```

Then in the base methods you should be able to use `pdata^.position1` and in the extended methods `pdata2^.position2`.

---

**4. If you'd prefer to not use pointers, you can use references instead:**

This option was proposed by [Stefan Roelofs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6433949/stefan-roelofs) in a [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657716/how-to-override-a-struct-in-a-derived-fb/72659660?noredirect=1#comment128464156_72659660).

```pascal
INTERFACE IDataProvider EXTENDS __System.IQueryInterface
METHOD GetDataARef : REFERENCE TO BaseModuleDataStruct

INTERFACE IDataProviderB EXTENDS IDataProvider
METHOD GetDataBRef : REFERENCE TO ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct

FUNCTION_BLOCK BaseModuleFB
VAR
    rdata: REFERENCE TO BaseModuleDataStruct;
END_VAR
METHOD FB_Init: BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains: BOOL; // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    bInCopyCode: BOOL;  // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    dataProvider: IDataProvider;
END_VAR
// Inside the FB_Init method: "THIS^.rdata REF= dataProvider.GetDataARef();"


FUNCTION_BLOCK ModuleWithExtraFunctionFB EXTENDS BaseModuleFB
VAR
    rdata2: REFERENCE TO ModuleWithExtraFunctionDataStruct;
END_VAR
METHOD FB_Init: BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains: BOOL; // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    bInCopyCode: BOOL;  // Internal built-in hidden argument. Don't touch!
    dataProvider: IDataProvider;
END_VAR
VAR
    success: BOOL;
    _dataProviderB: IDataProviderB;
END_VAR
// Inside the FB_Init method:
// success := __QUERYINTERFACE(_dataProvider, _dataProviderB);
// IF (success) THEN
//     THIS^.rdata2 REF= _dataProviderB.GetDataBRef();
// END_IF
```

Then, inside your Function Blocks you may want to use the `__ISVALIDREF()` operator to validate that the cast/conversion was successful. After that in the base methods you should be able to use `rdata.position1` and in the extended methods `rdata2.position2`.

NOTE: You may get many C0410 warnings:

`C0410:  COMPATIBILITY WARNING: A write Access to a Property of type REFERENCE calls the SET-Accessor for versions < 3.5.10.0 and writes the reference, but calls the GET-Accessor for versions >= 3.5.10.0 and writes the value! Use the operator REF= if you want to assign the reference.`

If this annoys you, you may disable the C0410 warning in your compiler (Project Settings).

---

---

***I uploaded an example PLCOpenXML file on [GDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yux7yfYXC1tZdEzEpe3oRBoCJ9sXiSpD/view?usp=sharing), you can try importing it and play around with it.***

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Very interesting to review the sample code you provided. You've actually provided the exact answer for the question I asked, so thanks! However I don't think I'll be using your code for these reasons:
* You are using a VAR_TEMP to make a local copy of the data. This works ok, but these variables are not available in methods of the FB. So I would have to make a local copy in each separate method. 
* You are copying the complete struct every cycle locally. I could probably solve this with a REFERENCE TO, but I haven't bothered.

Comment: Reasons for using a struct in the first place, is because these variables need to be retained/persisted. Declaring any retained variables in a FB will move the complete FB to retained memory. I think what I'll try to do is forget about retained variables and use the Codesys Recipe Manager instead.

Comment: I used VAR_TEMP as a demonstration, but ideally, you'd define Properties inside the interface to get/set those variables, for example your struct has `x: INT` and `y: REAL`, give the `IDataProvider` interface a INT Property by the name of X, and let's say you want y to be read-only, define a REAL Property with the GET only as Y. This way you could also abstract some data specific logic, for example check that x is positive in the setter to disallow negative x.

Comment: @StefanRoelofs I updated the sample code with Properties for the data providers. Also I added another possible solution with pointers, both in the answer and sample code, which may be easier for you to implement and use. However, as I noted in the answer, be extra careful when using pointers! Hope you can solve your problem ;)

Comment: I thought the solution you proposed yesterday was good: Group my data in a FB. Inject an interface to that FB into the class that needs it. Perfect to abstract away some data specific logic like you say. However it fell apart for 1 reason: It doesn't work with complex datatypes like arrays or structs :( `It is not possible to perform component access '.', index access '[]' or call '()' on result of function call. Assign result to help variable first.`

Comment: @StefanRoelofs as you noted, codesys unfortunately has many restrictions. If your structures have substructures or arrays inside, your options are to either define even more properties to access them, forgo interfaces entirely and use raw pointers, or combine the two. For the last option, you could use the DataProvider to get a pointer to the structure inside the DataProvider in the `FB_Init` method (constructor). This has the benefit of runtime checking for type safety (using QueryInterface), while having unrestricted access. I've updated the file on GDrive, so check it out. I added arrays.

Comment: I also got it working with complex datatypes like arrays. You just have to change the property from `ARRAY[1..2] OF REAL` to `REFERENCE TO ARRAY[1..2] OF REAL`. And also use the REF= keyword in the property getter. However I think I found a better/cleaner solution that works for me: Place data in a FB as local variables. Make this FB implement an empty interface. Give this interface to the module, and then use `__QUERYPOINTER` to get a pointer back to the data FB. Sample code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dbntrdXeMBJS0u-C2DUNng600hHbwqon/view?usp=sharing). Thx!

Comment: @StefanRoelofs I checked your example (and fixed a few things, like provider2 not extending provider1), I never thought about using `__QUERYPOINTER`. I tried it, and though it works, it isn't much better than using raw pointers as it seems this operator mostly ignores the type information. I updated the sample code on GDrive with with such case, so I'd advise caution if you use that method.

Comment: @StefanRoelofs actually, after a bit more testing using raw pointers at least throws an access violation exception if the wrong struct is passed to the child FB, so you can at least detect the issue in development and correct it. The methods with Interfaces are the most type safe, `__QUERYINTERFACE` correctly returns false when it should. `__QUERYPOINTER`, however, returns true even when it clearly shouldn't, and no access violation is thrown either, so the there's high risk for "silent" bugs! I'd recommend avoiding this method. (Sample code updated... again...)

Comment: I agree that using the __QUERYPOINTER approach would be too risky. But I think that I've found the perfect solution (for my needs anyway). See sample code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gAP3Z5jDF5WL0DXjk74kZdrfSgxySmw-/view?usp=sharing). It is basically the same as your example with interfaces with pointers, but cleaned up a little so it makes sense to me. Biggest change is that I use a reference instead of a pointer. So no more dereferencing pointers :)

Comment: @StefanRoelofs Glad you found something you are happy with. Using references like that always gave me C0410 compatibility warnings, which you can just ignore/disable if this doesn't affect you, but still I usually avoid them for that. I updated the answer once more with your solution for the sake of future reference for others ;)